# Having some trouble using Dirichlet's test to show series convergence,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

The series is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^\alpha}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Since the summand is a product of two factors, and the log factor is monotonically decreasing to zero, as n goes off to infinity, I want to use Dirichlet's test to show the convergence of this series, depending on the parameter of $\alpha$, which is the tricky part.

The second criteria to satisfy in order to be able to apply the test is for

$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^\alpha}$$

to be bounded for every positive integer $N$.  For $\alpha >1$, this is obvious, since it gives a convergent $p$-series.

So, I had thought that my answer was that this series converges for all $\alpha>1$.

Apparently not.

The complete interval of convergence is actually for $\alpha>0$.

Can I stay on this track and still use the Dirichlet test?  If so, how can I tweak the above partial sum to show that it is also bounded for $\alpha>0$, for all positive integers $N$?

Thanks

Comment: Dirichlet won't give you a good result - the limit of the ratios is $1$, which is the "undetermined" result.

Comment: Thanks so much @ThomasAndrews :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To show that we have convergence for $\alpha\gt 0$, use the inequality $\log(1+x)\lt x$ if $x\gt 0$.

To show we do not have convergence for $\alpha\le 0$, show first that we do not have convergence at $\alpha=0$. This can be done in various ways. One way is to use an estimate of $\log(1+1/k)$,

Another is to note that $\log(1+1/k)=\log(k+1)-\log k$ and then use telescoping.

Comment: Hi @AndreNicolas, thanks so much for your answer.  Using Taylor expansion, I convinced myself of the inequality that you showed and can now show the convergence for $\alpha$ >0, by comparison with a larger convergent p-series.  However, I am a little confused about the case for $\alpha$ =0.  The summand reduces to log(1 + 1/k) = log(k+l) - log(k), as you suggested to use.  A pretty cool observation, thanks :-).  But...doesn't this telescoping sum show the *convergence* of the series, and not divergence?  Thanks,

Comment: Or is it just simply the nth-term test -- the summands do not go to zero, and so we must have divergence?  Thanks,

Comment: The sum of the terms up to the $\log(1+1/n)$  term collapses to $\log(n+1)$.  This goes to infinity, kind of slowly, as $n\to\infty$. So the limit of the partial sums does not exist, or if you prefer, is infinite. It is not the $n$-th term test.

Comment: Proving $\log(1+x)$ is less than $x$ if $x\gt 0$ can be also done by letting $f(x)=x-\ln(1+x)$.  We have $f(0)=0$, and $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$. The derivative is positive for $x\gt 0$, so $f$ is increasing, and therefore $f(x)\gt 0$ if $x\gt 0$. Alternately, proving $x\gt \ln(1+x)$ is equivalent to showing $e^x\gt 1+x$, which is very clear from the series for $e^x$.

Comment: Ah, ok I see the divergence to infinity now for $\alpha$ = 0.  And thanks for the really cool function f(x) = x  - ln(1+x) and your using the derivative to show that it is increasing.  Have a great night, @AndreNicolas :-)